# "No route matches" error in Rails 3 when invoking own controller method from view (POST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, http-post, custom-routes

Rails champions

I've been programming with Ruby and Rails 2.x for quite a while and while I'm certainly not proficient in Rails, I'd still say that I had a nice grasp of the framework and the tools. However, I am currently working on my first Rails 3 project (currently using 3.0.5) and I am growing increasingly desperate with the new Rails 3 routing interface.

Of course, I have been following Ryan Bates' RailsCasts (http://railscasts.com) in general and on the topic in particular.
Of course, I have read many, many websites about the topic (e.g. [RailsGuides: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) or [The Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/), etc., etc...).
I am even one of those old-fashioned guys who reads books, so I have also been following the Beta Book on Rails 3 by The Pragmatic Programmers.
And, last but not least, I did try to find an appropriate answer on this site.

I guess you could say, that I really tried to find my way round before pestering you with my question. But nothing seems to really cover my problem. Yet, I am pretty sure, that the solution can't be too difficult. I've been trying to find a solution for days now I just don't see what my mistake is.

Let me first give you a quick rundown on what I already can do:

I have no problems with the standard Rails methods predefined by entries in routes.rb, such as:

```
resources :my_controller
```

I also managed to get some of my own GET-methods to work, e.g.:

```
# in routes.rb
resources :some_items do
  get :my_additional_method, :on => :member
end

# in a view of SomeItemController:
<%= link_to 'invoke additional method', [:my_additional_method, @some_item], :class => "some_css_class" %>
```

HOWEVER, the follwing situation is giving me real headaches:

```
# in ItemController
def my_method
  raise params.to_yaml
end

# in routes.rb
resources :items do
  post :my_method, :on => :member
end

# e.g. in edit view of ItemController:
<% form_tag ( my_method_item_path(@item), {:class => :some_css_class} ) do %>
...
<% end %>

# 'rake routes' output excerpt
my_method_item POST /items/:id/my_method(.:format) {:controller =>"items", :action=>"my_method"}

# ERROR during the rendering of the view
No route matches {:action=>"my_method", :controller=>"items", :id=>#<Item id: ...>}
```

I tried dozens of variantions of the above.
For example, the following variation **doesn't help**:

```
# variation of form_tag in view:
<% form_tag ( {:controller => "items", :action => "my_method", :id => @item }, {:class => :some_css_class} ) do %>
```

The only thing I got working - which, however, is NOT what I want - is the following:

```
# in ItemController
def my_method
  raise params.to_yaml
end

# in routes.rb
resources :items do
  post :my_method, :on => :collection
end

# e.g. in edit view of ItemController:
<% form_tag ( my_method_items_path(@item), {:class => :some_css_class} ) do %>
...
<% end %>

# 'rake routes' output excerpt
my_method_items POST /items/my_method(.:format) {:controller =>"items", :action=>"my_method"}
```

As you probably have guessed already, I lose the "id" param when invoking the method on the **collection** instead of the **member**.
Please note, that I am aware of how important the "s" at the end of the "item" is. I know you need to leave it out in certain situations and to add it in others.

Can anyone help me out here?
What is my mistake?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<% form_tag (my_method_item_path(@item), :class => :some_css_class, :method => :post ) do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Shiv, thanks for your answer.

It doesn't solve my problem, though. I don't need form_for. I really need form_tag.

Apart from that, my problem is, that while "my_method_item_path" is correctly transformed into {:controller => 'items', :action => 'my_method'} there is no route to match it and I don't know how to adjust my routing.

Tx, anyway.

Comment: I have modified my response using form_tag, this should work for you

Answer (score -1):

Got to this URL to learn about adding More RESTful Actions to a "resources"d controller:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

To add the following example method route:

```
/photos/1/preview
```

This will call the preview method of the photos controller with the ID 1